# Вместо текста - названия переменных

Tags: opencart, ocstore

Перенес с локалки на хостинг, все нормально, кроме одного - вместо текста выводятся названия переменных, в которых этот текст должен быть.

ocStore 2.3 на сервере Apache, Nginx, PHP 5.6.33

Comment: файлы локализации перенесли? язык фронта не переключали? файлы локализации текущего языка есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все оказалось банально просто - пропустил одну папку в пути в конфигах